Is BQP contained in BPP with Quantum Phase Estimation (QPE) oracle?
I am trying to see if the below proposition holds:

Proposition-1: $BQP\subseteq BPP^{QPE}$.

Here, QPE is the Quantum Phase estimation algorithm. QPE takes an eigenstate and the unitary matrix as input, while output is the corresponding eigenvalue.(Wiki)
My attempt: As per Theorem 3 in Wocjan et.al (2006), It is known that $BQP\subseteq BPP^{PES}$. Where PES is the Quantum Phase Estimation sampling problem.
The paper mentions an algorithm to solve PES using the Quantum phase estimation (QPE) algorithm. Rest is classical pre/post-processing. Thus,

Claim-1: I interpret that any classical computer with access to QPE can solve the PES problem. Or, $PES \in BPP^{QPE}$.

If Claim-1 is correct, then Propositon-1 follows directly from it. As, $BPP^{BPP^{QPE}}=BPP^{QPE}$.
My queries:

Is claim-1 correct?
If claim-1 is correct, can we say QPE is sufficient to capture the power of Quantum computation?


QPE has two parts: Hamiltonian simulation, repeated many times with the control register fed into an inverse Fourier transform. Wocjan and Zhou’s results shows sampling from the decomposition of $|\psi\rangle$ is inherently BQP complete. So I think yes, but I’m not sure…

@Mark, I do think so. The proposed algorithm by Wocjan and Zhaou to solve PES requires QPE as a subroutine; the rest are classical pre/post-processing.

*Zhang not Zhou or Zhaou. But both Hamiltonian simulation and the inverse Fourier transform are far from trivial…
